# How can I combine a file on lots of lines into one big line?

Tags: command-line, bash, unix

I have something like this:

```
a line here;
a new line here;
another line here;
```

and I want it to be like, where all lines are combined into a single line.

```
a line here;a new line here;another line here;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tr -d '\n' <filename>` will delete all newlines in the given file.

Comment: +1 for not resorting to perl for something so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -pechomp file1 > file2
```

Answer (score 1):

(Just in case someone on Windows needs this.) In PowerShell it's

```
-join (Get-Content filename)
```

or shorter:

```
-join(gc filename)
```